# Cannot read property 'format' of undefined - Build on Mac - Open the prog - Ionic 2 with Electron

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, electron, ionic3

If I want to build my app, which is Ionic 2 and Electron used to get native node modules. I get this error, if I want to build the program and open it.

Log-files while building:

```
electron-builder 19.22.1
Rebuilding native production dependencies for darwin:x64
Packaging for darwin x64 using electron 1.6.11 to dist/mac
⚠️  Application icon is not set, default Electron icon will be used
⚠️  App is not signed: cannot find valid "Developer ID Application" identity or custom non-Apple code signing certificate, see https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Code-Signing

All identities:
  1) 6C3F7754F6D009926038537F387FAB2791787B78 "com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.4d4f32455a31724551527a61443857327430692b61773d3d"
  2) AC427E392FE8EB003E7D5A19C841FC82BEC52A25 "iPhone Developer: philipp.fock@icloud.com (Y5UY9Y69QB)"
     2 identities found

  Valid identities only
  1) 6C3F7754F6D009926038537F387FAB2791787B78 "com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.4d4f32455a31724551527a61443857327430692b61773d3d"
  2) AC427E392FE8EB003E7D5A19C841FC82BEC52A25 "iPhone Developer: philipp.fock@icloud.com (Y5UY9Y69QB)"
     2 valid identities found
Building macOS zip
Building DMG
⚠️  Application icon is not set, default Electron icon will be used
```

This is my code in electron.js:

```
'use strict';
const electron = require('electron');
//const electronprinter = require('electron-printer');
// Module to control application life.
const {
    app } = electron;
// Module to create native browser window.
const {
    BrowserWindow
} = electron;

const {ipcMain} = require('electron');

const electronPrinter = require('printer');

const fs = require('file-system');

var imagemagick;

try {
    imagemagick = require('imagemagick');
} catch(e) {
    throw 'please install imagemagick-native: `npm install imagemagick-native`'
}


let win;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 600
    });

    var url = process.env.E_URL || url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../www/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    win.loadURL(url);

    // Open the DevTools.
    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on('closed', () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null;
});
}

ipcMain.on('get-printers', (event, arg)=> {
    console.log("ping");
    var printers = electronPrinter.getPrinters();
    console.log(printers);
    event.sender.send('get-printers-response', printers);
});

ipcMain.on('print-pdf', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg.pdf);
    console.log(arg.printer);
    try {
        var buf;
        if (typeof Buffer.from === "function") {
            // Node 5.10+
            buf = Buffer.from(arg.pdf, 'base64'); // Ta-da
        } else {
            // older Node versions
            buf = new Buffer(arg.pdf, 'base64'); // Ta-da
        }
        console.log("hello");

        electronPrinter.printDirect({
                data: buf,
                printer: arg.printer,
                type: 'PDF',
                success: function (id) {
                    console.log('printed with id ' + id);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error('error on printing: ' + err);
                }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.message);
    }

});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});


app.on('activate', () => {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

You can see. I use the native node-module printer. 
Then my start site is index.html of generated Ionic2 browser code.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "benutzerPanel",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": {
    "name": "Philipp Fock"
  },
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nf start",
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "electron dist": "electron .",
    "ebuild": "yarn run build && node_modules/.bin/build",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/printer": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer": "^0.7.3",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.5.3",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ngx-electron": "^1.0.3",
    "node-printer": "^1.0.2",
    "printer": "^0.2.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "@types/electron": "^1.4.34",
    "electron": "^1.6.2",
    "electron-builder": "^19.22.1",
    "foreman": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic": "3.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "DPos",
  "main": "electron/electron.js",
  "config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.banana.Pos",
    "electronVersion": "1.6.11",
    "asar": true,
    "files": [
      "www/**/*",
      "electron/*"
    ]
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is with this block here

```
 var url = process.env.E_URL || url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../www/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
});
```

I am guessing you are setting the environment variable `process.env.E_URL` in a js script somewhere to `http://localhost:{port}`. This is fine when spinning up the development server but not when packaging the app during the electron build. This variable doesn't remain permanently set.

Try adding the following to the top of the `electron.js` file.

```
const path = require('path')
const url_lib = require('url')
```

Then change where you are setting the URL for the electron `BrowserWindow` to the following.

```
 var url = process.env.E_URL || url_lib.format({
pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../www/index.html'),
protocol: 'file:',
slashes: true
});
```

This should fix the issue. The issue was that `url` was undefined during the electron build.